# Show last image from directory on website

Tags: wordpress, web

I have a video camera that uploads via FTP only to preset folders. It uploads to a tree, like this `/www/wp-content/uploads/camer/10.121.0.202/2021-01-02/D3`. I need to show the last uploaded image on the website. I need to take this folder `/www/wp-content/uploads/camer/10.121.0.202/` and find the newest file and show it on the website. My website is running on WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether there is a dedicated plugin for this but the following lets you do basically everything.

1. Install [Insert PHP Code Snippet](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/)
2. Add the following code snippet and save it as e.g. 'getlatestfile'. Adjust the `base_path` and maybe the relative `../` according to which page you want to display the image OR make it absolute.

```php
<?php
$base_path = 'wp-content/uploads/camera';
$latest_folder = scandir($base_path, SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);
$latest_file = scandir($base_path  . "/" . $latest_folder[0], SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);
echo "<img src='../" . $base_path . "/" . $latest_folder[0] . "/" . $latest_file[0] . "' />";
?>
```

3. Add `[xyz-ips snippet="getlatestfile"]` to the page where you want your image.

I assumed that your *camera* folder only contains folders and that they all have the same date format. Also the files inside the date folder like 'D3' should be ascending in time (hexadecimal). So the next image would be 'D4' etc.

---

EDIT:
If D3, D4, ... are folders which contain the images add another `scandir`

```php
<?php
$base_path = 'wp-content/uploads/camera';

$latest_date_folder = scandir($base_path, SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);
$latest_folder = scandir($base_path  . "/" . $latest_date_folder[0], SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);
$latest_file = scandir($base_path  . "/" . $latest_date_folder[0] . "/" . $latest_folder[0] , SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);

echo "<img src='../" . $base_path  . "/" . $latest_date_folder[0] . "/" . $latest_folder[0] . "/" . $latest_file[0] . "' />";
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I ran into a problem. I have this plugin and I put your code in it, but when I try to go to the site only icon of "broken image" appear. And I find out why it is because url to image is "https://www.burin.cz/wp-content/uploads/camer/10.121.0.202/2021-01-02/D3/" but there should be image name after D3 folder. I am totally lost in this codes so I am not able to find solution and I again asks for you time and help, thank you

Comment: @Matthew I though _D3_ would be the final image so it makes sense that it does not display. The first `scandir` looks for the latest folder by sorting it alphabetically and descending. If we find the latest date folder we search for the latest image in there.
So you would need to insert another `scandir`.
Please clarify whether there is always and only a _D3_ folder and how the images are named.

Comment: Ah I see. Yeah then the edited part of my answer should work. (The line with `$latest_folder` is a bit useless then but you can change it as soon as you understand whats going on)

Comment: Finally, I have it. It is working. Thank you so much.